# Terraform: merge maps of lists and combine the lists from duplicate keys

Tags: terraform

I have something like so

```
locals {
  roles = [
    {
      role = "roles/admin"
      members = ["user:user@example.com"]
    },
    {
      role = "roles/viewer"
      members = ["user:user2@example.com"]
    }
  ]
}
```

I want my modules to be able to export their own list of roles like

```
roles = [
    {
      role = "roles/viewer"
      members = ["user:newperson@example.com"]
    }
]
```

And then be able to merge these things together to get

```
locals {
  roles = [
    {
      role = "roles/admin"
      members = ["user:user@example.com"]
    },
    {
      role = "roles/viewer"
      members = ["user:user2@example.com", "user:newperson@example.com"]
    }
  ]
}
```

I know if I stored everything as maps I could merge the maps and it would work fine as long as there are no duplicate keys. But in this case I explicitly want to be able to have duplicate keys so that one module doesn't need to care about any of the other modules.

**Update** I was able to achieve this by doing something like so:

```
roles = distinct(flatten([
    for rm in local.role_maps : [
      for role, members in rm :
      {
        role = role
        members = sort(distinct(flatten([
          for m in local.role_maps :
          m[role] if lookup(m, role, null) != null
        ])))
      }
    ]
  ]))
```

Answer (score 6):

This seems like a good application for a [`for` expression](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/expressions.html#for-expressions) using the `...` grouping modifier, which can produce a map of lists by grouping by the keys.

```
variable "custom_roles" {
  type = list(object({
    role    = string
    members = list(string)
  })
}

locals {
  default_roles = [
    {
      role    = "roles/admin"
      members = ["user:user@example.com"]
    },
    {
      role    = "roles/viewer"
      members = ["user:user2@example.com"]
    }
  ]
  all_roles = concat(
    local.default_roles,
    var.custom_roles,
  )

  # First we'll project the inputs so that we have one
  # role/member pair per element.
  flat_roles = flatten([
    for r in locals.all_roles : [
      for m in r.members : {
        role   = r.role
        member = m
      }
    ]
  ])

  # Then we can use that flattened list to produce a map
  # grouped by unique role key.
  merged_roles = {
    for k, v in local.all_roles : k => v...
  }

  # Finally, if the list-of-objects representation was
  # important then we can recover it by projecting that
  # merged_roles map back into the list shape.
  merged_roles_list = tolist([
    for role, members in local.merged_roles : {
      role    = role
      members = tolist(members)
    }
  ])
}
```

In the above, `local.merged_roles` is a map of lists, like this:

```
{
  "roles/admin"  = ["user:user@example.com"]
  "roles/viewer" = ["user:user2@example.com", "user:newperson@example.com"]
}
```

You could potentially use that map directly, but just in case the list-of-objects form was important I included `local.merged_roles_list` which should match the structure you asked for your question.

Comment: This is a nice and easy to follow solution, but I think your `merged_roles` isn't quite right. I think you want to operate on `flat_roles` instead of `all_roles`.