# Parsing json in terraform locals

Tags: json, terraform

I have another question about JSON parsing. Imagine I have this JSON:

```
{
    "all_dogs" :[
        {
            "name": "foo", 
            "groups": ["morning", "evening"]
        }, 
        {
            "name": "bar",
            "groups": ["evening", "saturday"]
        }, 
        {
            "name": "feet", 
            "groups": ["afternoon"]
        }
    ]
}
```

I can extract all the groups like this:

```
locals {
  all_dogs = jsondecode(file("${path.module}/dogs.json"))

  all_groups = toset(flatten(local.all_dogs.all_dogs[*].groups))
}
```

Now, I’m trying to create a MAP. Each group is a key of the map and values of the maps are the different dogs in that group.
So I would like to create a map like this:

> afternoon = [feet]
> evening= [foo, bar]
> morning= [foo]
> saturday= [bar]

I'm trying with something like this and I tried several options... But I can't make it work.

```
output "ex" {
  value = flatten([
    for group in local.all_groups: [
      for dog in local.all_dogs : {
        group = group 
        dog = dog 
      }
    ]
    ]
  )
}
```

Later on, I would like to use that map to provision some resources. Is this eventually possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
locals {
  all_dogs = jsondecode(file("${path.module}/dogs.json"))

  groups = flatten([for d in local.all_dogs.all_dogs : [for g in d.groups : { key : g, value : d.name }]])
}
```

The value for local `groups` will be a list of tuples and it will look something like this:

```
groups = [
  {
    "key" = "morning"
    "value" = "foo"
  },
  {
    "key" = "evening"
    "value" = "foo"
  },
  {
    "key" = "evening"
    "value" = "bar"
  },
  {
    "key" = "saturday"
    "value" = "bar"
  },
  {
    "key" = "afternoon"
    "value" = "feet"
  },
]
```

Now we have to create a `map` from this list:

```
output "my_map" {
  value = {
    for g in local.groups : g.key => g.value...
  }
}
```

This will produce the following output:

```
my_map= {
  "afternoon" = [
    "feet",
  ]
  "evening" = [
    "foo",
    "bar",
  ]
  "morning" = [
    "foo",
  ]
  "saturday" = [
    "bar",
  ]
```

Comment: Nice. You do it in two steps basically. Very neat. Thank you!!!!

Comment: Similar examples is the following: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62071136/7661119 . The same approach is used here as well.